# DrawPolygon problem in DrawDynamicLayer

Tags: arcobjects

I have a class that inherits from BaseDynamicLayer and I override the DrawDynamicLayer() method. Is there something special that needs to be done for a successful inDynamicDisplay.DrawPolygon(poly) call? The method crashes every time I call it with a "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040218." I can use the same point collection to create a Polyline and call DrawPolyline(polyLine) without a problem. I can also successfully use all the other draw commands, like DrawMarker() & DrawRectangle().

Answer (score 2):

Is your polygon a simple geometry? You may need to invoke simplify and then try to draw it.

Here's an [example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000304000000) of simplifying a polygon

```
//Set the IsKnownSimple property to false, 
//otherwise simplification will not take place.
ITopologicalOperator2 topoOp = geometry as ITopologicalOperator2;
topoOp.IsKnownSimple_2 = true;
topoOp.Simplify();
```